# Open XAVA How to Put Default value and Join column of another table

Tags: openxava

**1 .For default value I have tried :**

```
@Required 
@Column(name="semester")
@DefaultValueCalculator(value=StringCalculator.class, properties=@PropertyValue(name="value", value="173"))
private String semester;
```

**Getting error :**

> Error calculating default value

**2 . Another Problem is I want to view column of another table into a table.**

> Table . 
>    - Room [id, name]
>    - RoomAssigned [id , capacity , type ,status ]

In view/UI , I am showing RoomAssigned which has CRUD .

```
Now its showing column - 
[id,capacity,type,status]
```

I want to add another column [name] from "Room" table . Here "Room" id is foreign key.

```
I want to get a view with view / UI : 

 [id,name,capacity,type,status]
```

I am new in OpenXava.Thanks in advance.

Comment: About the first problem you should put the stacktrace here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About the second point, you have to put the reference name in the @View members, use a @ReferenceView in the reference and create a @View in the referenced entity.

Read this documentation first:
http://openxava.wikispaces.com/view_en

Comment: Do you mind if i ask you another question here ? Because stackoverflow not taking any question from me. @javierpaniza

Comment: Hi Shifat, put your OpenXava questions in OpenXava forums: https://sourceforge.net/p/openxava/discussion/419690/